# The application was unable to start correctly (0xc0000005)

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I'm using Delphi XE2 in my system. When I'm trying to compile new Delphi 32 bit application I'm getting **(cgrc.exe - Application Error)** *The application was unable to start correctly (0xc0000005). Click OK to close the application* error. And I'm unable to create any applications with single Form either.

Answer (score 3):

Based on Symantec forum there is a problem with Symantec Endpoinnt protection blocking cgrc.exe but only on 32 bit Windows. Same problem doesent ocurs on 64 bit Windows.

You can check their forums thread to get some more info on this: http://www.symantec.com/connect/forums/cgrcexe-resource-compiler-binder-cannot-run-windows-7-32bit

Comment: Thanks a lot for both of them

Comment: Wait who deleted another answer that was posted in this thread and all the comments which lead to the conclusion that AV might be the casue? And David there were your coments also in here.

Comment: This answer should stand alone. At the moment it depends crucially on the comments to the deleted answer.